# Change font of tikz diagrams in html produced by make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I'm building an html document from latex file using `make4ht`. I've successfully set the font of document body to Libertinus Serif using CSS. But I can't set the font that's used by make4ht to build tikz diagrams. Can someone help me do that?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% These lines don't help either:
% \usepackage{fontspec}
% \setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
% \setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
% \setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}

``Lorem'' ``ipsum''

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (x) {``Lorem''};
  \node[right=of x] (y) {``ipsum''};
  \draw[->] (x) to (y);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My command is `make4ht -l -m draft -c myconfig.cfg -f html5 main.tex`, and the contents of `myconfig.cfg` is

```latex
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Css{
  @import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/libertinus-serif');
  body{ 
    font-family: "Libertinus Serif", serif; 
  }
} 

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The result is:

[image: web page screenshot]

You can clearly see that apart from size difference the fonts aren't the same. Tikz picture is using the default Latin/Computer Modern font, and not Libertinus Serif used by the paragraph above it (pay attention to the tail of u and the nose of r).

How do I make tikz picture render with the same Libertinus Sans font?

Comment: Could you explain how these fonts your used to compile with at your PC will seen or used by someone on the internet when you upload your HTML to your server later on? I mean you are saying you want to use "Libertinus Serif" in the HTML.  But how will the user's browser see/find these fonts if they are not installed on their PC? This part is not clear to me.

Comment: in PDF, the fonts will be part of the PDF file itself. i.e. included in the PDF file. but with HTML, how will you make these fonts available to others to view your web pages?

Comment: I'll upload the font files together with the page (to my static http server) and include them via custom css. It's a standard practice with static site generators like Jekyll.

Comment: But it's not related to my question actually. My question was about changing the font used on tikz pictures (rendered as svg). I included details of what I'm trying to do for context.

Answer (score 3):

All fonts are suppressed in the `--lua` mode of TeX4ht, because we need to prevent the loading of OpenType fonts, which causes a fatal error. You can still manually switch to Type 1 fonts just for the TikZ environment. This configuration file should do that:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/begin}{\fontfamily{LibertinusSerif-TLF}\selectfont}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<style type="text/css">
  @import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/libertinus-serif');
  body{ 
    font-family: "Libertinus Serif", serif; 
  }
</style>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Note that I also changed your configuration for the text font, because the `\Css` command adds stuff at the end of the CSS file, but the `@import` rules must be at the top of the CSS file. This configuration puts them directly to the HTML document, where it works.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, it works great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a way to redefine fonts used by `\textsf` and `\texttt` in Tikz or I'll have to define my own macros instead of these commands?

Comment: @ivan you would need to use simillar commands to `\fontfamily` to select correct fonts for sans-serif and typewriter styles.